# Testing Prefrontal cortex

Tags: measurement, abnormal-psychology

Is there a test to see if the Prefrontal cortex of someone works normally? especially a simple test like a questionnaire that you give the individuals to fill out and based on their answer you obtain results.

Comment: Welcome. What is normal?

Answer (score 2):

Prefrontal cortex is most closely associated with the group of cognitive functions termed "executive function" - measures of executive function do not measure prefrontal cortex per se because (almost all) brain functions are not simply localized to one area, but one would expect major lesions of the prefrontal cortex to impair executive function, as would pharmacological manipulations that preferentially target prefrontal cortex.

Here's a list from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuropsychological_test#Executive_function) of some tests that involve executive function (not fully inclusive):

> Behavioural Assessment of Dysexecutive Syndrome (BADS)
>
> CNS Vital Signs (Brief Core Battery)
>
> Continuous performance task (CPT)
>
> Controlled Oral Word Association Test (COWAT)
>
> d2 Test of Attention
>
> Delis-Kaplan Executive Function System (D-KEFS)
>
> Digit Vigilance Test
>
> Figural Fluency Test
>
> Halstead Category Test
>
> Hayling and Brixton tests
>
> Kaplan Baycrest Neurocognitive Assessment (KBNA)
>
> Kaufman Short Neuropsychological Assessment
>
> Paced Auditory Serial Addition Test (PASAT)
>
> Rey-Osterrieth Complex Figure
>
> Ruff Figural Fluency Test
>
> Stroop task
>
> Test of Variables of Attention (T.O.V.A.)
>
> Tower of London Test
>
> Trail-Making Test (TMT) or Trails A & B
>
> Wisconsin Card Sorting Test (WCST)
>
> Symbol Digit Modalities Test
>
> Test of Everyday Attention (TEA)

The appropriateness of a particular test would depend on other circumstances: for example, some of these tests are more appropriate to research in healthy folks, others are more appropriate for monitoring symptoms of/diagnosing dementia.

Additionally, the prefrontal cortex is a big area of the brain with involvement of lots of different functions. Focal lesions or individual differences could easily impact some prefrontal cortical function while sparing others. Prefrontal cortex should not be thought of as "one thing" but rather as a diverse brain *region*.